# CSS Background image positioning on text link rollover

Tags: css, hyperlink, rollover

I have text links that I am trying to use a background image with on rollover (`link.gif` is transparent, `linkhover.gif` is the rollover image).

The code I have below is working except the positioning is not.

```
.navlink {
background:transparent url('graphics/link.gif') center top no-repeat;
height:70px;}

.navlink:hover {
background-image: url('graphics/linkhover.gif');}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try making the background take up the full size, like this

```
.navlink {
    background: url('graphics/link.gif');
    height:70px;
}

.navlink:hover {
    background: url('graphics/linkhover.gif');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: 100%;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Zeaklous/ALJ8Z/)

If you have a parent element around `.navlink`, then you can just put `height:100%` and remove `height:70px;` and it will stay proportional. If you want to disregard proportion and just have it fill the parent you can put both `height:100%` and `width:100%`

**EDIT**

Since I found out the `navlink`s are all `<a>`: you can't have `background-attachment: fixed` because it makes the parent's background change instead of the `navlink`'s (for what reason I don't know)

Updated code

```
.navlink {
    text-align:center;
    background: url('graphics/link.gif');
    background-repeat: no-repeat; /* This applies to :hover as well */
    background-position: center; /* This applies to :hover as well */
    text-decoration: none; /* To remove the underline */
}
.navlink:hover {
    background: url('graphics/linkhover.gif');
}
```

[**Updated demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Zeaklous/ALJ8Z/4/) based on the structure of your site which you provided in the comments

Next time when writing your question you should include the relevant HTML, that would have made it much easier to help you with the problem

**EDIT 2**

After some playing I believe I got your site the way you want it using this:

```
.navlink {
    padding-top:30px;
    text-align:center;
    background: url('graphics/link.gif');
    text-decoration: none;
}
.navlink:hover {
    background: url('graphics/linkhover.gif');
    background-position: center -55px;
    background-repeat:repeat-y;/*This is optional, taking it out makes it repeat*/
    text-decoration: none; 
}
```

Comment: It'd be helpful to see the desired result so we can help further

Comment: hmm.. this did something but not quite what I wanted.. I have several links (the main navigation all in a row across the top of the site), each with navlink as it's class. This code seems like it stretched that one image across the background of all the links.

Comment: Here is what I have now:

    `.navlink {padding-left:30px;
    line-height:70px;
    background:transparent url('graphics/link.gif') center top no-   repeat;}

    .navlink:hover {
    background-image: url('graphics/linkhover.gif');}`

Here is the site I'm working on: http://domakitchencafe.com/website2.0/

I'm trying to get the text links (across the top) to move down so the little graphic will be above them. I still need to get it to center above them also.

Comment: Ah, the issue with my code is due to you having it in a table row (that would have been very useful information, you should include a bit more of your structure next time). I'm working on an updated solution now. Also the fact that `navlink`s are all `<a>` tags makes it more difficult

Comment: I apologize, I haven't built a website in years and incredibly rusty. I'm sorry to cause any confusion! Is there anything I can do to make that easier? I'm used to doing this with javascript, where the links are just images that swap, just thought I'd try this technique out. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Let me know if you need something else

Comment: hmm.. It's working in your example but on my site, not at all. http://domakitchencafe.com/website2.0.

Comment: Apparently it doesn't like `background-image`. Switched it to just `background` and it worked fine. Also, `background-repeat: no-repeat` seemed to break it as well so I took it out

Comment: Works perfectly!! Thank you so much!!

Just one more question. I had to add `padding-left:30px;` to put space between each of the links and that causes the graphic to be off center. Is there a fix for that? I could also use a transparent gif as a spacer but I have a feeling there's an easy css fix that I just don't know of!

Comment: A cool little trick to keep the original positioning of the furthest right element the same using the approach in the comment above is to apply `margin-right:-15px` to only that last element

Answer (score 0):

You should make a sprite, put the images next to each other in one file and adjust the background-position on :hover. The CSS should be like this:

```
.navlink {
    background-image: url('image');
    background-position: top left;
}

.navlink:hover {
   background-position: top right;
}
```

You can achieve a cool effect when adding an CSS3 transition.
The image will then slide to the rollover state!